# Draw random numbers from the Gumbel distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, statistics

**Question:** I would like your help to draw random numbers from the Gumbel distribution with scale `mu` and location `beta` in Matlab.

I want to use the definition of the Gumbel distribution provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) (see the PDF and CDF definitions on the right of the page).

**Notice:** The package `evrnd` in Matlab, described [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/evrnd.html), cannot be used (or maybe can be used with some modifications?) because it considers flipped signs.

Let me explain better this last point.

Let's fix the scale to `0` and the location to `1`.

Now, following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) and other textbooks (for example, [here](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/train1201.pdf) p.42) the Gumbel PDF is

`exp(-x)*exp(-exp(-x))`

In [Matlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/extreme-value-distribution.html) though it seems that `evrnd` considers random draws from the following PDF:

`exp(x)*exp(-exp(x))`

You can see that in Matlab `-x` is replaced with `x`.

Any idea on what is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Quantile_function_and_generating_Gumbel_variates), the inverse cumulative distribution function is

> `Q(p) = mu - beta*log(-log(p))`

From this function, the [inverse transformation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) can be applied. Thus

```
sz = [1 1e6]; % desired size for result array
mu = 1; % location parameter
beta = 2.5; % scale parameter
result = mu - beta*log(-log(rand(sz)))
```

gives `result` with i.i.d. Gumbel-distributed numbers. Plotting the histogram for these example values gives

```
>> histogram(result, 51)
```

[image]

---

If you want to use the [`evrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evrnd.html) function (Statistics Toolbox), you only need to change the sign of the output. According to the documentation,

> `R = evrnd(mu,sigma,[m,n,...])`
>
> The version used here is suitable for modeling minima; the mirror image of this distribution can be used to model maxima by negating `R`.

Thus, use

```
result = -evrnd(mu, beta, sz);
```